# Dynamic set object reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox in excel sheet with name txtI_8. How select this object in vba code (target is change bordercolor of this textbox according cell interior color)?

```
'working:
ActiveSheet.txtI_8.BorderColor = 0

'working:
Dim ww As Object
Set ww = ActiveSheet.txtI_8
ww.BorderColor = 123456

'No error, but color is not changed (shape container???)
Dim ww As Object
Set ww = ActiveSheet.Shapes("txtI_8")
ww.OLEFormat.Object.Border.Color = 123456
```

Thanks

Comment: If the first two are working, why not use them?

Comment: because i have a lot of textboxes on the sheet and I need dynamycally change object name... Something like ActiveSheet.VARIABLE.BorderColor, where VARIABLE="txtI_8"....

Answer (score 0):

This changes the border color of all OLE objects. If you have any other objects apart from text boxes and you don't want to change their color, you will have to check within the loop whether the object is a text box or not.

```
Dim tBox As Object

For Each tBox In Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects
    tBox.Object.BorderStyle = 1
    tBox.Object.BorderColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
```

Comment: This is working.... but with big time consumption... I can check object.name for required textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately any answer is not working for me, I figure out something like this

```
Sub txtboxline()

    Dim objtxt As Object
    Set objtxt = ActiveSheet.Shapes("txtI_8")
    objtxt.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 2 'red color

End Sub
```